# Number Suffixes in names?

Tags: names

I can't seem to find any information on this. You know how people in the west have names like James Smith IV, is there something along that line for the Japanese?

Answer (score 0):

The counter `～世` is used after the person's name. For example,

> King George **IV** =  ジョージ**4世** ([see here](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B8%E3%83%A7%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B84%E4%B8%96_(%E3%82%A4%E3%82%AE%E3%83%AA%E3%82%B9%E7%8E%8B))).